# calculating average of 3 months profit when input 1 date

Tags: excel

I have a table of profit for different vendors with range of date from OCT 2017 to AUG 2018. The intention is to input one single month and return with the average profit of the three previous months and three following months. (eg. input FEB 2018, return with average of DEC 2017, JAN 2019, FEB 2018, also return with average of FEB, MAR, APR 2018). Tried `hlookup` but seems did not work for this situation. Please advise.

[image: screenshot of excel file]

```
    OCT 2017    NOV 2017    DEC 2017    JAN 2018    FEB 2018    MAR 2018    APR 2018    MAY 2018    JUN 2018    JUL 2018    AUG 2018                            
Autozone    " $4,653 "  " $5,584 "  " $8,277 "  " $7,564 "  " $7,321 "  " $6,420 "  " $7,568 "  " $3,546 "  " $9,954 "  " $8,849 "  " $2,325 "                          
Walmart " $9,838 "  " $9,979 "  " $2,655 "  " $4,795 "  " $9,811 "  " $8,179 "  " $7,896 "  " $1,689 "  " $7,244 "  " $8,969 "  " $1,189 "                          
Target  " $8,359 "  " $7,683 "  " $4,607 "  " $4,224 "  " $6,221 "  " $8,519 "  " $5,058 "  " $9,184 "  " $9,699 "  " $1,292 "  " $1,080 "                          
Advanced Auto Parts " $3,674 "  " $4,619 "  " $3,817 "  " $8,741 "  " $9,118 "  " $5,542 "  " $1,578 "  " $9,853 "  " $8,153 "  " $4,710 "  " $4,519 "
```

Comment: Please post your data as text so we can copy and paste.  This way we can test scenarios before posting an answer.

Comment: Just posted the data in text, thanks

Answer (score 0):

pre:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($2:$5,0,MATCH(H8,1:1,0)):INDEX($2:$5,0,MATCH(H8,1:1,0)-2))
```

post:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($2:$5,0,MATCH(H8,1:1,0)):INDEX($2:$5,0,MATCH(H8,1:1,0)+2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, if the return would be for just one vendor, I assume it will be =AVERAGE(INDEX($2:$2,0,MATCH(H8,1:1,0)):INDEX($2:$2,0,MATCH(H8,1:1,0)-2)) for Autozone?

Comment: It seems like the calculation is not correct to me tho

Comment: @jasond1011 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.